# s3 boto upload fails randomly + python

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I want to upload files from s3 using boto 2.38 with python 3.4 and Django.

the two first retries doesn't work but the last worked fine (For the retries, it is executed manually not automatically.)

I get this error:

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 750, in send_file
    chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 951, in _send_file_internal
    query_args=query_args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 664, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1030, in _mexe
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 940, in _mexe
    request.body, request.headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 844, in sender
    http_conn.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 888, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

In the log, I have the right host name. By searching on the web I found that I must provide the host for the connection to s3 and as I have many buckets in many regions, I didn't specify the host (or should I consider all cases of regions ? I know that in Boto3 there is an improvement on this...):

```
bucket: 'NameOfTheBucket' is in eu-west-1
```

The big problem is that I can not reproduce the error so If anyone can help, I will be very grateful.

I added a part of my code:

```
 s3 = connect_s3(
        aws_access_key_id=xxxxx,
        aws_secret_access_key=xxx,
        is_secure=xxxxxx)
 self.s3_bucket = s3.lookup(self.s3_bucket_name)
```

the problem is in this part of the code:

```
 def put_s3_file_onepart(self, filename, key_name, headers):
    key = self.s3_bucket.new_key(key_name)

    key.BufferSize = CHUNK_SIZE

    with open(self.abs_path(filename), 'rb') as fp:
        key.md5, key.base64md5 = key.compute_md5(fp)

    with open(self.abs_path(filename), 'rb') as fp:
        key.send_file(fp, headers=headers) <==========

    key.close()
```

In my opinion, it is related to chuncked file. Thanks for the help.

Comment: We need to see code that provides a minimal example of the problem you are experiencing + "the two first retries doesn't work but the last worked fine" you need to explain what you mean by this

Comment: that sounds like you lost internet connection or something

Comment: @conrad yes it can explain why I can not reproduce it and it is not working randomly